# Ajax Success function not calling after returning from Controller ? MVC

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My jQuery code looks like:

```
$("#create").click(function(e) {  
    var myModel =
                {
                    "TribeName": $('#TribeName').val()
                };

var jsonToPost = JSON.stringify(myModel);
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Create/',
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    data: jsonToPost,
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            alert('asd');
            $('#butn').trigger('click');
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        if (!$('.modal-header').hasClass('alert-danger')) {
            $('.modal-header').removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
            $('.delete-confirm').css('display', 'none');
        }
        $('.success-message').html(err.statusText);
    }
});
})
```

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Tribe model)
{
    try
    {
        using (StructureEntities db = new StructureEntities())
        {
            var tribe = db.Set<Tribe>();
            tribe.Add(new Tribe {TribeName = model.TribeName });
            //db.Tribes.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    // return RedirectToAction("NewsCreated", model);
}
```

My making it type get I am getting back to success method but due to type I can't send my data to controller.

In this above ajax I can send and save my data but cant get back to success method of ajax

I searched a lot before posting this question

Hopes for your suggestions

Comment: it is not hitting error either. I tried by removing if clause even than it is not hitting alert

Comment: To confirm: your MVC Action is called fine with the code you've provided (type:post and saves the data), it's just not getting back to the js?

Comment: Can you please try `data==true` or check-in console log but in some case error occurred in controller action your jquery code break.

Comment: yes its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because true don't return as bool it returned as string 
you'r code should be like

```
        if (data=="True") {
            alert('asd');
            $('#butn').trigger('click');
        }
```

Comment: Except, of course, it's not checking for true, it's checking for truthy.  `if ("True") alert("yep")`

Comment: And your code would fail because it would be "True" which != "true"

Comment: @TareqHajer i tried your code buddy its not coming to success method :(

Comment: @Doc can you explain how this answered your question?  Not going back to success: with or without the `if`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

1) Create one model class for generic using

```
 public class AjaxActionResult
 {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }
 }

//In your action 


public ActionResult Create(Tribe model)
{
    try
    {
        using (StructureEntities db = new StructureEntities())
        {
            var tribe = db.Set<Tribe>();
            tribe.Add(new Tribe {TribeName = model.TribeName });
            //db.Tribes.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(new AjaxActionResult()
        {
            Message = "Your message",
            Success = true
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new AjaxActionResult()
        {
            Message = ex.Message,
            Success = false,
            Data = ex
        });
    }
}
```

In jquery, you need to change as below

```
$("#create").click(function(e) {  
    var myModel =
                {
                    "TribeName": $('#TribeName').val()
                };

var jsonToPost = JSON.stringify(myModel);
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Create/',
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    data: jsonToPost,
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Success) {
            alert('asd');
            $('#butn').trigger('click');
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        if (!$('.modal-header').hasClass('alert-danger')) {
            $('.modal-header').removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
            $('.delete-confirm').css('display', 'none');
        }
        $('.success-message').html(err.statusText);
    }
});
})
```